# Column invalid in select list because it is contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I know similar questions have been covered for this topic, I've looked through the answers but I just can't work out how to apply to this query unfortunately.
I know that adding 'pe.short_name' to GROUP BY isn't the best way to handle this either.
Any suggestions very much appreciated..

> Column 'pe.short_name' invalid in select list because it is contained
>   in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

```
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(s.description, 13, 1) = '.'
            THEN LEFT(s.description, 17)
        ELSE LEFT(s.description, 12)
        END WBSCode
    ,pe.short_name
    ,pn.description ProjectName
    ,(
        SELECT description
        FROM structure
        WHERE structure_code = pe.code346
        ) ActivePortfolio
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ast.Description = 'WAIO'
            THEN anc.Description
        ELSE site.Description
        END SiteFunction
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(jv.description, 5, 1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(jv.description, 4)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(jv.description, 7, 1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(jv.description, 6)
        ELSE jv.Description
        END AS JointVenture
    ,(
        SELECT description
        FROM structure
        WHERE structure_code = pe.code79
        ) AssetClassification
    ,(
        SELECT description
        FROM structure
        WHERE structure_code = pe.code390
        ) InvestmentSize
    ,(
        SELECT RIGHT(import_code, 6)
        FROM structure
        WHERE structure_code = pe.code79
        ) AssetClassCode
    ,CAST(p.period_start AS DATE) Period_Start
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN be.currency_code = 'AUD'
                AND @Currency = 'AUD'
                THEN be.amount
            WHEN be.currency_code = 'USD'
                AND @Currency = 'USD'
                THEN be.amount
            WHEN be.currency_code = 'AUD'
                AND @Currency = 'USD'
                THEN be.amount * ip.pfn_exch_rate_on_date(p.period_start, be.currency_code)
            WHEN be.currency_code = 'USD'
                AND @Currency = 'AUD'
                THEN be.amount * (ip.pfn_exch_rate_on_date(p.period_start, be.currency_code) / ip.pfn_exch_rate_on_date(p.period_start, 'AUD'))
            END) Amount
FROM fm_budget_entry be
JOIN fm_period p ON be.period_id = p.period_id
JOIN fm_budget_line bl ON be.line_id = bl.line_id
    AND bl.version_id = @FinancialVersion
JOIN fm_budget_line_attrib la ON la.line_id = bl.line_id
    AND la.line_attrib_code = 'Wbs138'
JOIN structure s ON la.line_attrib_value = s.structure_code
JOIN fm_account fa ON bl.account_code = fa.account_code
JOIN planning_entity pe ON pe.planning_code = bl.structure_code
JOIN structure ast ON ast.structure_code = pe.code713
    AND ast.Description IN (@Assets)
JOIN structure pn ON pn.structure_code = pe.planning_code
LEFT JOIN structure site ON site.structure_code = pe.code37
LEFT JOIN structure_tree tr ON tr.dsc_code = pe.planning_code
    AND tr.anc_Depth = 5
LEFT JOIN structure anc ON anc.structure_code = tr.anc_code
LEFT JOIN fm_version v ON v.version_id = bl.version_id
LEFT JOIN structure pc ON pc.structure_code = s.father_code
LEFT JOIN structure jv ON pc.father_code = jv.structure_code
    AND jv.father_code <> 'Wbs138Root'
WHERE fa.account_type_code IN (@FundingType)
    AND p.period_id BETWEEN @StartDate
        AND @FinishDate
    AND pe.code346 IN (@ActivePortfolio)
GROUP BY CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(s.description, 13, 1) = '.'
            THEN LEFT(s.description, 17)
        ELSE LEFT(s.description, 12)
        END
    ,pn.description
    ,pe.code346
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ast.Description = 'WAIO'
            THEN anc.Description
        ELSE site.Description
        END
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(jv.description, 5, 1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(jv.description, 4)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(jv.description, 7, 1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(jv.description, 6)
        ELSE jv.Description
        END
    ,pe.code79
    ,pe.code390
    ,CAST(p.period_start AS DATE)
ORDER BY 1
    ,CAST(p.period_start AS DATE)
```

Comment: well!  that's a horrible query!

Comment: add  `pe.short_name` field behind group by clause.

Comment: This query is horrific. I hate to be the soul that has to main it. To your question, (a) aggregate ```pe.short_name``` by wrapping it in SUM() or some other aggregate function, (b) add it to the group-by (which you said you didn't want) in-which case you have a separate row for each distinct value, or (c) omit the field all together. Without seeing your data, it's hard to tell you what's best.

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me who thinks this....I've very new to SQL and have been tasked with maintaining a bunch of reports..none of which I've written...I must admit I'm struggling with these queries..>I thought it was just me being new to SQL...Thanks very much for the suggestions!

Comment: I bet you are missing a not in that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(s.description, 13, 1) = '.'
            THEN LEFT(s.description, 17)
        ELSE LEFT(s.description, 12)
        END WBSCode
    ,pe.short_name
    ,pn.description ProjectName
    ,(
        SELECT description
        FROM structure
        WHERE structure_code = pe.code346
        ) ActivePortfolio
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ast.Description = 'WAIO'
            THEN anc.Description
        ELSE site.Description
        END SiteFunction
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(jv.description, 5, 1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(jv.description, 4)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(jv.description, 7, 1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(jv.description, 6)
        ELSE jv.Description
        END AS JointVenture
    ,(
        SELECT description
        FROM structure
        WHERE structure_code = pe.code79
        ) AssetClassification
    ,(
        SELECT description
        FROM structure
        WHERE structure_code = pe.code390
        ) InvestmentSize
    ,(
        SELECT RIGHT(import_code, 6)
        FROM structure
        WHERE structure_code = pe.code79
        ) AssetClassCode
    ,CAST(p.period_start AS DATE) Period_Start
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN be.currency_code = 'AUD'
                AND @Currency = 'AUD'
                THEN be.amount
            WHEN be.currency_code = 'USD'
                AND @Currency = 'USD'
                THEN be.amount
            WHEN be.currency_code = 'AUD'
                AND @Currency = 'USD'
                THEN be.amount * ip.pfn_exch_rate_on_date(p.period_start, be.currency_code)
            WHEN be.currency_code = 'USD'
                AND @Currency = 'AUD'
                THEN be.amount * (ip.pfn_exch_rate_on_date(p.period_start, be.currency_code) / ip.pfn_exch_rate_on_date(p.period_start, 'AUD'))
            END) Amount
FROM fm_budget_entry be
JOIN fm_period p ON be.period_id = p.period_id
JOIN fm_budget_line bl ON be.line_id = bl.line_id
    AND bl.version_id = @FinancialVersion
JOIN fm_budget_line_attrib la ON la.line_id = bl.line_id
    AND la.line_attrib_code = 'Wbs138'
JOIN structure s ON la.line_attrib_value = s.structure_code
JOIN fm_account fa ON bl.account_code = fa.account_code
JOIN planning_entity pe ON pe.planning_code = bl.structure_code
JOIN structure ast ON ast.structure_code = pe.code713
    AND ast.Description IN (@Assets)
JOIN structure pn ON pn.structure_code = pe.planning_code
LEFT JOIN structure site ON site.structure_code = pe.code37
LEFT JOIN structure_tree tr ON tr.dsc_code = pe.planning_code
    AND tr.anc_Depth = 5
LEFT JOIN structure anc ON anc.structure_code = tr.anc_code
LEFT JOIN fm_version v ON v.version_id = bl.version_id
LEFT JOIN structure pc ON pc.structure_code = s.father_code
LEFT JOIN structure jv ON pc.father_code = jv.structure_code
    AND jv.father_code <> 'Wbs138Root'
WHERE fa.account_type_code IN (@FundingType)
    AND p.period_id BETWEEN @StartDate
        AND @FinishDate
    AND pe.code346 IN (@ActivePortfolio)
GROUP BY CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(s.description, 13, 1) = '.'
            THEN LEFT(s.description, 17)
        ELSE LEFT(s.description, 12)
        END
    ,pe.short_name
    ,pn.description
    ,pe.code346
    ,CASE 
        WHEN ast.Description = 'WAIO'
            THEN anc.Description
        ELSE site.Description
        END
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(jv.description, 5, 1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(jv.description, 4)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(jv.description, 7, 1) = ' '
            THEN LEFT(jv.description, 6)
        ELSE jv.Description
        END
    ,pe.code79
    ,pe.code390
    ,CAST(p.period_start AS DATE)
ORDER BY 1
    ,CAST(p.period_start AS DATE)
```